# Use android as xbox360 wireless adapter?

Tags: wi-fi, game-controllers

I have a rooted cynogen mod Lg P500.

I can connect my xbox360 to my laptop for bridging a connection. but have recently moved to ubuntu so the bridging is a mission and a half.

So I was wondering if it was possible to use an android phone as an xbox360 wireless adapter.

By this I mean:

My android is connected to my networks wifi.

I want to connect my xbox360 to the android and connect to xbox live.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you ask on http://askubuntu.com/ about bridging with Ubuntu? It really shouldn't be very difficult, I've done it on the command line often enough.

Answer (score 5):

This will almost certainly be impossible.  Your XBox doesn't have USB drivers for your Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible if your rooted your phone and wrote an installed a new kernel usb driver which made it look like a supported network adapter.  Needless to say that would be a project requiring quite a bit of expertise and effort - it's probably going to be cheaper to get a supported adapter, and not tie up your phone in the process.